# Is ~と used the same as ~ないと in this case?

Tags: grammar, meaning, word-choice, quotes

誓うか必ず戻ると was used when a character asked another to promise to return.

Isn't it supposed to be 戻らないと? Promise that you must come back?

My understanding is "~nai to" is used for "must" where as "~to" is used for "if/when" you do something.

What meaning the "~to" mean in this sentence?

Comment: More context would help. A "dangling" と may mean と +いう、誓う、思う、etc. based on context, but just to make sure.

Comment: That was the whole thing. The next sentence was just 約束くれるか？ Reiterating the first line of vowing/promising.

Answer (score 2):

This sentence is inversion and と is used as a particle for quotation. It means 必ず戻ると誓うか.

"~nai to" is used for "must" as you said, but this is rarely used with 誓う. So 誓うか必ず戻らないと(いけないと) is unnatural.

Comment: Is that inversion a formal language structure? In conversation, I would expect it to sound like "誓うか、必ず戻ると", where a speaker is saying something like "Do you swear? That you'll be back?", but the absence of a comma or a pause leads me to believe that it may actually be a formal Japanese language structure.

Comment: It is a way used in conversation.

Comment: Ah I see quotation! In the say way as って？ Then that makes sense. Couldn't find it in any grammar.

Comment: Yes, って is also used as a particle for quotation.